# How to access localhost from android emulator?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, android-emulator, localhost

I am studying Xamarin from this tutorial - [Signup user to ASP.NET Identity from Xamarin Forms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t0v4srA4NhA&index=1&list=PLpbcUe4chE78YvgIMtmgNEmRGyGJcsQdF). Everything is working if a send request with postman. But if I want to use android emulator it is not working. And I cannot use UWP, because developer mode has to be enabled and I don’t have admin rights on my company computer. I enabled developer mode on my private computer and it is working on UWP but it is not working on android emulator. In the tutorial is used UWP and the guy said that for the android emulator is needed some configuration, but he did not tell any details.

I read many articles and it seems that problem is in the connection between my backend (running on localhost) and android emulator. Is it correct that android emulator is a separate machine trying to call my localhost? I tried to change localhost to 127.0.0.1 or 10.0.2.2 and I tried all options from [this article](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking). But it is not working.

Am I right that localhost has to be changed? If so, where? Or is problem somewhere else?

Api services Register method:

```
    public async Task<bool> RegisterAsync(string email, string password, string confirmPassword)
    {

        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Email: " + email);
            var client = new HttpClient();

            var model = new RegisterBindingModel
            {
                Email = email,
                Password = password,
                ConfirmPassword = confirmPassword
            };
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);

            HttpContent content = new StringContent(json);
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            var response = await client.PostAsync("http://localhost:49205/api/Account/Register", content); 

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + e);
            throw;
        }
   }
```

Exception if I use localhost:

```
{System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection refused
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x000b6] in <bcdc1df2b3724ab69797f3819a126346>:0 
at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request) [0x0016d] in <bcdc1df2b3724ab69797f3819a126346>:0 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x0003a] in <bcdc1df2b3724ab69797f3819a126346>:0 
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction, System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x0000f] in <fcbf47a04b2e4d90beafbae627e1fca4>:0
```

Bad request if I use 10.0.2.2:

```
{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, 

Headers: {Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 Date: Thu, 17 May 2018 09:08:41 GMT Connection: close Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii Content-Length: 334 }}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`localhost` refers to your local machine. It's a common mistake that people think that the Android emulator (or iOS for that matter) is also part of `localhost` since it is running on the same machine. But this isn't the case.

The emulators are running as a device in your device and mimic the working as if it was a physical device. It has it's own IP address and cannot reach your `localhost` loopback address. Your app runs as a application on another machine, namely te emulator. It gets a bit confusing when using UWP, since this *does* run as an application on your local machine.

That is why you would have to use the network address of your machine where the server application is hosted. This address typically starts with `192.168.x.x` or `10.x.x.x` and can be found in the network settings of your machine.

It seems that you already discovered this. When using the `10.0.2.2` address you receive a HTTP 400. Which means something in your request wasn't right, but you can conclude from this that the server application can actually be reached. But the content of the request causes a problem in your server app. Since you do not provide any code for the `/Account/Register` endpoint it is impossible to tell what is going on there. Put a breakpoint in your server code, retry the request and try to see why a HTTP 400 is triggered.

Comment: My request was correct. I had to use this address 192.168.x.x and run Visual Studio as admin. Then i had to go to applicationhost.config file (in .vs folder, not in solution explorer) - .vs/config/applicationhost.config.

Comment: I changed this lines (49205 is my port):
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" /> and
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:49205:localhost" /> there is this line 3x i don’t know why, i had to change them all, sometimes it is creating these lines again so i have to change it. To this:
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080: \*" /> and
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="\*:49205:\*" />
And now it is working

Answer (score 0):

127.0.0.1 is localhost; it's the IP address of every local machine,
that means you try to create a request from an Android App to an Android device

In another word, you try to connect with an Android device, not with a computer Localhost.

for that, you need to change the localhost in the computer from 127.0.0.1  to the current IP4 of your computer.

now try this extension and follow the instructions to do that in Visual studio:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti